# Android Constraint Layout Inside ListView - Last Item Style Is Broken

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I don't understand why is the last item of the `ListView` kinda "buggy". Why am I missing in there, it is because the ListView doesn't fulfill the parent on the bottom? I don't think so because I set a minHeight in my Item.

I've also tried to set a padding to the bottom (as another stack answers mentionned) but it didn't did the trick.

First, let's see the graphic result:

[image]

Here is my **Activity**:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Activity.SelectSequenceStartPractise">

    <fragment android:name="fr.izio.enhancedtabata.Fragment.MainHeader" android:id="@+id/main_header" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
        android:layout_marginTop="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/main_header"
        android:id="@+id/select_a_sequence_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Select a sequence"
        android:fontFamily="@font/exo2"
        android:textColor="@color/design_default_color_primary"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:textAlignment="center"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/sequence_selection_container_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/select_a_sequence_text" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is my **Item** (for the adapter):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.CardView"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/material_on_primary_emphasis_high_type"
    android:minHeight="72dp">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="72dp"
        android:padding="8dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sequence_name_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fontFamily="@font/exo2"
            android:text="My super sequence"
            android:textColor="@color/design_default_color_primary"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sequence_time_duration"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fontFamily="@font/exo2"
            android:textColor="@color/design_default_color_secondary"
            android:text="Duration: 50 s"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sequence_pause_time_duration"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/exo2"
            android:textColor="@color/design_default_color_secondary"
            android:text="Pause: 10 s"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sequence_contains_cycles_number"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fontFamily="@font/exo2"
            android:textColor="@color/design_default_color_secondary"
            android:text="Contains 5 cycles"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

And finally, here's the getView method from **Adapter**:

```java
    @NotNull
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final Sequence sequence = super.getItem(position);

        if (convertView == null) {
            // Let's inflate the view
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.sequence_item_selection_start_practice, parent, false);
        }

        TextView sequenceName = convertView.findViewById(R.id.sequence_name_text);
        TextView sequenceDuration = convertView.findViewById(R.id.sequence_time_duration);
        TextView sequencePauseDuration = convertView.findViewById(R.id.sequence_pause_time_duration);

        if (sequence != null) {
            sequenceName.setText(sequence.name);
            sequenceDuration.setText("Cycle duration: " + String.valueOf(sequence.sequenceDuration) + " s.");
            sequencePauseDuration.setText("Pause duration: " + String.valueOf(sequence.sequencePauseDuration) + " s.");
        }

        return convertView;
    }
```

Why is the last item of the ListView not respecting the constraints I entered in the item?

Comment: Why are you still using ListView instead of RecyclerView?

Comment: I have some constraints where I work for, and one of it is to not use RecyclerView. Also, answer a question by another question is not helping.

Comment: Just for information, I tried with RecyclerView and it didn't help. I can share the code. I'm pretty sure there's something wrong in the layout part.

Answer (score 0):

The "android:layout_height" value should be "wrap_content" or "0dp" when you align child view to top and bottom of parent.

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
```

set "minHeight" for a child view

Comment: For which element?

Comment: For all TextView

Comment: I feel pretty dumb, I had `\n` character is my datas... Thanks for helping :)